# How would I configure my webpack.config.js file to properly navigate to other html pages?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack

I'm kind of stuck on how to configure `webpack.config.js` file in order for it to navigate to other html pages.  In other words, a multi-page react.js website.

I want to navigate to `About.html` upon clicking on `About` in `Main.jsx` file.  I'm trying to use Routing but I know I'm way off.

I know that the meat of this is in `webpack.config.js` so I made an attempt below to see if it works by trying to mimic the `HtmlWebPackPlugin({})` of `index.html`, but it doesn't.

Note: I'm not using `create-react-app` for my project. I'm just trying things out outside of `create-react-app` environment and instead, onto other environments. I installed `Babel` and all the other stuff manually.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `Main.jsx`:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.goToAbout = this.goToAbout.bind(this);
    }

    goToAbout() {
        console.log("clicked");

        return(
            <Router>
                <Route path={"/About"} component={Main}/>
            </Router>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="button is-primary" onClick={this.goToAbout}>About</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;

const wrapper = document.getElementById("create-article-form");
wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, wrapper) : false;

// about page (my attempt) 
const aboutWrapper = document.getElementById("about-page"); 
aboutWrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, wrapper) : false;
```

Here's `About.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>About Section</h1>
    <div id="about-page"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's `webpack.config.js`:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),

        // my attempt
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({ 
            template: "./src/About.html",
            filename: "./About.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Routing has nothing to do with Webpack - on your "About" route, use a component for `About`, i.e. change `About.html` to a component

Comment: @ic3b3rg As I mentioned above, I want to redirect to About.html file, not another react.js component

Comment: ok, try removing the component and changing path to `path="/About.html"`

Comment: oh wait a minute - you don't want to return DOM from your onclick event - your router needs to go into your `render` and the `button` you have should be a `Link`

Comment: @ic3b3rg ah ok, I see what you mean.  May you please provide me with an example using my scenario?  Because `<Route/>` must take a `component` attribute but in my case, I don't want it to redirect to another js component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this has to do with webpack.

Instead of

```
<button className="button is-primary" onClick={this.goToAbout}>About</button>
```

use:

```
<Link to="/About/">About</Link>
```

If you are trying to link to a page that is not inside of react, you could use something like:

```
<a href={`${window.location.origin}/about`} />`
```

You'll want to use a standard HTML anchor tag with the href set to the location where you want navigate to.

Comment: hmm ok, so with `<a href={`${window.location.origin}/about`} />`, I'm trying to put the file path for `About.html` but it isn't recognizing it.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of issues here - this should get you pointed in the right direction:

**Main.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import {Link, Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router';  // <- this should be 'react-router-dom' -- upgrade?

const Main = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/About.html" />
    <Switch>
    <Link to="/About.html">About</Link>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById("app"));  // <- your React app should be mounted to a single element
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/js/Main",  // <- replace with actual path to Main.jsx
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
instead of <Route path={"/About"} component={Main}/> use 
<BrowserRouter>
<div>
<Switch>
<Link  path="/about" component="{Main}">
</Switch>
</div>
</BrowserRouter>or

<Link to="/about"></Link> and 

and import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```